# Picture manager not opening up after authentication during multi upload in images library

Tags: authentication, site, office-integration, picture-library, image-upload

While trying to upload multiple images in a picture/image library, i am getting authentication popup, after which the **picture manager doesn't open up.**

This is happening to many users. What could be the cause here? I'm using SP 2007 and Office 2010. Picture manager is installed on all machines.

Comment: try to add that site into the trust zone and then try...one more thing you can use fiddler and trace it on which item it need credentials.